# Distribution of containerized applications to end users

Tags: docker, containers, software-distribution

I have containerized an application which is comprised of a Node.js application, Nginx, and MongoDB. I'm currently using Docker Compose to start and stop the application on my development machine.

I'd like to distribute the application, along with the volume that contains the MongoDB database files, so that an end user can *easily* start the application on their computer and point their web browser to it.

Some factors I'm considering:

- The end user is almost certainly not familiar with containerization and is probably not comfortable playing around in a terminal.
- The end user is likely to be using macOS or Windows, but Linux should be supported.
- Asking the user to install Docker is possible, but I don't like that it requires Hyper-V on Windows, which conflicts with other software such as VirtualBox.

I could write a cross-platform GUI application that manages Docker with simple "start" and "stop" buttons. However, I am not married to using Docker if there is an easier path forward. Should I look into something like Facebook's [executable archives](https://github.com/facebookincubator/xar/)?

Comment: I have a similar question, and similar doubts about the large system footprint and potential incompatibilities of Docker Desktop requirements on Mac and Windows. Obviously you didn't get any answers on SO, did you come to any conclusions?

Comment: I didn't. I think I would probably just go with a Virtual Box VM, running Docker inside, if I had to.